# VMware ESXi: Automatic restart of an VM

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine, esxi

Here I have a machine with VMware ESXi 5. One of my VMs is shutting down after some time (I can't prevent this). However, I want the VM to be automatically restarted if it was shut down. But I can't find an option in my vSphere client to do this.

So is there a way to do an automatic restart?

Answer (score 2):

ESXi 5 has option to start and stop VM automatically

Go to ESX host configuration and left side you can see "Virtual Machine Startup/Shutdown"

Go to properties and select "Allow virtual machine to start and stop automatically with the system"

in Startup Order move your VM machine in "Automatic Startup section"